# ros2 launch using ignition while run command line in ros2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How do you load some command line such as `"ros2 topic pub --once /S0 std_msgs/msg/Float64 '{data: 1.5}' && ros2 topic pub --once /S1 std_msgs/msg/Float64 '{data: 1.5}'"` while leave ignition bridge in the launch file?

Even better, how do you create a node where you can load ros2 command line?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/395777/ros2-launch-using-ignition-while-run-command-line-in-ros2/) by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2022-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) on 2022-02-09**:
I'm not sure I follow your question. Are you asking how to run `ros2 topic pub ...` from a launch file? If so, use the launch.actions.ExecuteProcess action.

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2022-02-14**:
Yes!! I think that's the one.

How do you use it exactly? I don't think I've ever seen it before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you're looking for the `ExecuteProcess` Launch action:

```
from launch import LaunchDescription
from launch.action import ExecuteProcess

def generate_launch_description():
    return LaunchDescription([
        ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ros2', 'topic', 'pub', '--once', '/S0',
                            'std_msgs/msg/Float64', '{data: 1.5}']),
        ExecuteProcess(cmd=['ros2', 'topic', 'pub', '--once', '/S1',
                            'std_msgs/msg/Float64', '{data: 1.5}']),
    ])
```

Another example can be found in the launch examples: https://github.com/ros2/launch/blob/master/launch/examples/launch_counters.py#L112

---

Originally posted by [ChuiV](https://answers.ros.org/users/30013/chuiv/) with karma: 1046 on 2022-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kak13](https://answers.ros.org/users/71412/kak13/) on 2022-02-16**:
Thank you so much!